# Where all to use volatile keyword in C

Tags: c, embedded, driver, volatile

I know volatile keyword prevents compiler from optimizing a variable and read it from memory whenever it is read. Apart from memory mapped registers, what are all the situations where we need to use volatile? Given a conforming compiler, do I have to declare test_var as volatile in both scenarios?

### 1.

### In file1.c

```
int test_var=100;


void func1()
{
    test_var++;
}
```

### In file2.c

```
extern int test_var;

void func2()
{
    if(test_var==100)
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

### 2.

### In file1.c

```
int test_var=100;

void func1()
{

}
```

### In file2.c

```
extern int test_var;

void func2()
{
    if(test_var==100)
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

Comment: That is probably required in multithreaded applications as well.

Comment: Note that with your variable declared as being of the `extern` storage class, the compiler is restricted in its ability to optimize out reads and writes to that variable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and that would be a classic bug, see my answer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen very good answer btw

Comment: https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword

Comment: @tofro "_the compiler is restricted in its ability to optimize out reads and writes to that variable_" How so?

Answer (score 6):

memory mapped I/O is the **only** generic use of `volatile` in C. *)

With POSIX signals, a `volatile` can also be used together with the type `sig_atomic_t` like this:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t signal_occured = 0;
```

Neither of your scenarios should require `volatile` at all. If all you're interested in is a guarantee that the value is updated between different compilation units, see tofro's comment, `extern` already guarantees that. Particularly, `volatile` is **not the correct tool** for thread synchronization in C. It would only introduce bugs, because, as you state it, it **does** require actual read and write accesses to the variable, but it does **not** enforce their proper ordering with respect to threads (it's missing memory barriers, google for details).

Note that this is different from some other languages where `volatile` is designed to work between threads.

In an embedded system, `volatile` might be good enough for communicating between an ISR (interrupt service routine) and the main program, when combined with a data type that's read/written atomically, just like `sig_atomic_t` for POSIX signals. Consult the documentation of your compiler for that.

---

*) The C standard mentions this, along with the use-case of "asynchronously interrupting functions", only in a footnote, because memory-mapped I/O is outside the scope of the language. The language just defines the semantics of `volatile` in a way that make it suitable for memory-mapped I/O.

Comment: Inasmuch as you seem to be distinguishing between standard C and POSIX (or other) C extensions, your opening sentence is a bit odd.  As far as I am aware, standard C does not provide memory-mapped I/O, so shouldn't you say "there is **no** generic use of `volatile` in C"?

Comment: @JohnBollinger well, footnote 134 in section 6.7.3 explains this intended use of `volatile` ("*A volatile declaration may be used to describe an object corresponding to a memory-mapped
input/output port*"), but it also mentions "asynchronously interrupting functions" (the use-case with POSIX signals), so you're probably right ;)

Comment: @JohnBollinger as the "reason to be" for `volatile` most probably was memory-mapped I/O, I'll leave it and just add a footnote.

Comment: This answer is misleading. There is explicit usage of `volatile` in the C standard, namely for signal handlers and `longjmp`, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In neither of your examples is `volatile` necessary.

`volatile` is necessary:

1. anywhere a variable may be changed outside of the control of a single thread of execution,
2. anywhere the variable access is required to occur even when it semantically has no effect.

Case 1 includes:

- memory mapped I/O registers,
- memory used for DMA transfers,
- memory shared between interrupt and/or thread contexts,
- memory shared between independent processors (such as dual port RAM)

Case 2 includes:

- loop counters used for empty delay loops, where the entire loop may otherwise be optimised away completely and take no time,
- Variables written to but never read for observation in a debugger.

The above examples may not be exhaustive, but it is the semantics of `volatile` that are key; the language only has to perform an explicit access as indicated by the source code.

Comment: The examples "memory shared between interrupt and/or thread contexts" and "memory shared between independent processors (such as dual port RAM)" are **dangerous** in C. In short: There's *something* necessary, but typically more than just `volatile`. `volatile` is, in general, useless for these cases.

Comment: @FelixPalmen : I am not sure that "useless" is entirely true - not a complete solution for sure.  To assume the problem is solved with `volatile` alone *is* dangerous; however it remains a circumstance in which `volatile` plays a role.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Dangerous does not always mean useless though.

Comment: @Clifford as soon as you use a construct that ensures proper synchronization between threads, `volatile` is superfluous. ISRs on embedded platforms might be an exception if your environment/compiler gives you some guarantees, but apart from that -- if you spot a `volatile` along the lines of multiple threads accessing the same data, you spot a bug.

Comment: A more extensive article than is reasonable on SO can be found at http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4442490/1/C-keywords--Don-t-flame-out-over-volatile, and the basics of volatile in embedded systems at http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword

Comment: @FelixPalmen : It is probably not convenient in SO comments for you to explain the "superfluous" comment - I'd need clarification.  
 Please feel free to edit my answer if you feel there is something important to add (or perhaps remove) - I'd appreciate it. Superfluous is not of course dangerous however.  Matters of synchronisation and atomicity are important aspects _not_ addressed by `volatile`, but those are not perhaps the subject of the question.

Comment: @Clifford your first link already tells everything necessary: "*In most multi-threaded setting you will use a variant of enter_critical and exit_critical region [...] Thus having volatile objects inside this region serves no purpose.*" (page 4). So yes, `volatile` for thread synchronization is *dangerous* in general (sometimes hiding bugs), and most of the time useless because the correct tool does all that's needed.

Comment: @FelixPalmen : I am not sure I advocated "'volatile' for thread synchronization".  The part you mentioned is followed by a quote from Linus Torvalds _""volatile" doesn't help anything at all with memory ordering and friends, so it's insane to think it "solves" anything on its own.”_. The critical point being "on its own".  He is wrong of course it does solve some things on its own, just not _"memory ordering and friends"_ - context is everything!

Comment: @FelixPalmen :  To be clear I have never used a processor for which this is a problem, so your input is valuable.  On Cortex-M it is recommended for portability across ARM platforms to use DMB, but is redundant on Cortex-M itself.

Comment: "_as soon as you use a construct that ensures proper synchronization between threads, volatile is superfluous_" Yes but sometimes no additional construct is needed; f.ex. for a flag that says "stop processing and exit as soon as possible", a volatile boolean is enough.

Comment: @Clifford In most cases, doing anything to enforce correct memory visibility between cores or diff CPU will make volatile redundant and only a pessimization, and a confusing one (as ppl will suppose that making a few variables volatile is helpful while often you would need to make almost all shared objects volatile to even have correct semantics)

Answer (score 1):

Besides extensions such as memory mapped devices, in standard C `volatile` has two use cases: interaction with signal handlers and modification of objects across usage of `setjmp/longjmp`. Both are case were there is unusual flow of control that an optimizer may not be aware of.

Comment: memory mapped devices are no "extensions", they are just something that might be present "outside", a property of the environment, and they *are* mentioned in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In C microcontroller applications using interrupts, the `volatile` keyword is **essential** in making sure that a value set in an interrupt is saved properly in the interrupt and later has the correct value in the main processing loop.  Failure to use `volatile` is perhaps the single biggest reason that timer-based interrupts or ADC (analog-digital conversion) based interrupts for example will have a corrupted value when flow of control resumes after the processor state is returned post-interrupt.  A canonical template from Atmel and GCC:

```
volatile uint8_t flag = 0;

ISR(TIMER_whatever_interrupt)
{
    flag = 1;
}

while(1) // main loop
{
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        <do something>
        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Without the `volatile` it's guaranteed to **not** work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from memory mapped registers, what are all the situations where
>   we need to use volatile?

If

1. execution is **purely sequential** (no threads and no signals delivered asynchronously);
2. you don't use `longjmp`;
3. you don't need to be able to **debug a program compiled with optimizations**;
4. you don't use constructs with vaguely specified semantics like **floating point operations**;
5. you don't do useless computations (computations where the result is ignored) as in a benchmark loop;
6. you don't do timings of any pure computations, that is anything that isn't I/O based (I/O based such as timings of accesses of network requests, external database accesses)

then you probably have no need for volatile.