# Is a read of 8 bytes on modern intel x86 guaranteed to by sane if 8byte written by different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, atomic

```cpp
struct Data {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};
```

Would the read of each double be sane, if read on a different thread, but only one other thread is writing to each of a,b,c?

What is the scenario if I ensure `Data` is aligned?

```cpp
struct Data {double a,b,c; } __attribute__((aligned(64));
```

This would ensure each of the a,b,c are aligned to 64,64+8, 64+16... so always aligned to 8*8=64 bit boundary.

This question [alignment requirements for atomic x86 instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415256/alignment-requirements-for-atomic-x86-instructions) and it's answer makes me think that it's perfectly valid to write to `Data::a/b/c` from another thread and simultaneously read them without use of `std::atomic`.

Yes I know `std::atomic` would solve this, but that's not the question.

Comment: It would be safe IF there was a guarantee that the compiler would use those atomic x86 instructions.   Meeting the alignment requirements does not mean the compiler will use those instructions.    Providing such a guarantee would mean lost optimisation opportunities, so I'd suggest it is unlikely to be the default.    So, unless you write your code to ensure thread safety (e.g. using `std::atomic`) there is no guarantee that a read would be "sane" if a write of the same variable occurs on another thread.

Comment: So what actually *is* the question, it mixes machine level semantics and C++ in an odd way, and the answer for each is opposite, because C++ likes to take away guarantees that the hardware gave you.

Comment: @harold I am under specific hardware, intel i7, in this case... and I was wondering if I could simply use a struct of aligned doubles and read and write from/to them without atomics, since my requiredment is only a sane read for aligned 8 bytes.

Comment: @themagicalyang in assembly you can do that. In C++, well maybe, but the compiler can ruin things. Overly hypothetical things aside, it may move a store out of a loop and do it only once at the end, or move a load out of a loop and do it only once at the start - then there are no torn loads or anything like that but your threads wouldn't be communicating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, aligned 8-byte loads/stores are guaranteed atomic by the x86 ISA, since P5 Pentium. [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86)

**But this is C++; there's no guarantee that stores and reloads aren't optimized away**.  Write in one thread and read in another is C++ Undefined Behaviour; compilers are allowed to assume it doesn't happen, **[breaking naive assumptions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387181/mcu-programming-c-o2-optimization-breaks-while-loop/387478#387478)**.  This lets them keep C++ objects  in registers across multiple reads/writes, only eventually storing the final value. (including global variables or memory pointed-to by some pointer.)

Since you didn't already know that `volatile` or `atomic<double>` are needed for this reason, better read about the *other* things that `atomic<>` does for you, like ordering wrt. other operations unless you use `memory_order_relaxed` (the default is `seq_cst` which makes stores expensive, but on x86 loads are still just as cheap).  And (like `volatile`) the assumption that other threads might have modified an object between accesses in this thread.  See [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num), some of which is relevant for FP loads and stores.

Lockless programming in C++ is *not* simple, unless you have zero need for synchronization / ordering.  Then you "just" have to make sure you tell the compiler what you mean, with `atomic<T>`, or as a hack with `double`.

---

Since GCC's `std::atomic<double>` with `mo_relaxed` doesn't compile efficiently, you *might* want to roll your own by making members `volatile` if you only care about portability. (or even casting to `(volatile double*)` like the Linux kernel's `READ_ONCE` / `WRITE_ONCE` macros).  With clang you can just use `atomic<double>` with memory_order_relaxed and things will compile efficiently.  See [C++20 std::atomic<float>- std::atomic<double>.specializations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680928/c20-stdatomicfloat-stdatomicdouble-specializations/58945360#58945360) for example of what you can do before C++20; C++20 only adds atomic RMW add/sub for `double` so you don't have to roll your own with a CAS loop.

`volatile` will probably still defeat auto-vectorization, but you can of course use `_mm_load_pd` or whatever.  (See also [Atomic double floating point or SSE/AVX vector load/store on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055402/atomic-double-floating-point-or-sse-avx-vector-load-store-on-x86-64) - note that SIMD load/store aren't necessarily atomic even if aligned.  Also undocumented is whether they're per-element atomic, although that *is* I think safe to assume.  [Per-element atomicity of vector load/store and gather/scatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012574/per-element-atomicity-of-vector-load-store-and-gather-scatter))

[When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) normally never, except maybe as a workaround for GCC which won't emit efficient asm for `atomic<double>`, and where we know exactly how `volatile` compiles to asm.

---

**BTW, you only need `alignas(8)` to make sure members are 8-byte aligned.**  Aligning the struct to a whole cache line doesn't hurt, unless it wastes space.

For performance: if different threads are using different variables in the same cache line, that's "false sharing" and terrible for performance.  **Don't group your shared variables together in one struct unless they're usually read or written as a group.**  Otherwise you definitely want them in separate 64-byte cache lines.

---

**Note that a data-race on a `volatile` is still ISO C++ undefined-behaviour, but if you're using GNU C (as required by your `__attribute__`), it's pretty much well defined.  The Linux kernel uses it** for its own hand-rolled atomic (along with inline `asm` for barriers) so you can assume it's not going to be intentionally unsupported any time soon.

TL:DR: in GNU C it does more or less work to think of `volatile` as atomic with `mo_relaxed`, for aligned objects small enough to be naturally atomic.

Comment: I 'd add that if different threads are accessing different members, false sharing is something to consider.

Comment: @AProgrammer False sharing is only when different threads write right? If only one thread writes and others read then there is no issue.

Comment: @themagicalyang: Not *quite*.  If thread A is chugging along, re-reading `double a` every iteration in case it changed, that can hit in cache.  Thread B storing to `double b` in the same line as `a` will invalidate that line in all other cores, interfering with thread A even if thread A never reads `b`.